# What is then correct link to my app in the Apple AppStore?

Tags: swift, hyperlink, app-store

I tried to figure out the correct link to my app in the Apple AppStore but I found many different answers...
I just want to provide a link on my website which directly leads to the app in the AppStore of the region the user is in. So users from Germany should see the app in the German store and users from the US should see the app in the American store.
Some links, for example on Apples "Market with the App Store" website use the "us" or "de" country region shortcut. Do I have to change this for every country or is there a link which just leads to the correct AppStore which is selected in the settings of the iPhone?
Thanks!

Comment: https://www.apple.com/lae/itunes/link/

Comment: Thank you, but this also seems to be country specific as I have to select a country to generate a link. I´m looking for a link which is valid for every country.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure they work across countries; I frequently access an iTunes link and get a 'this app is not available in your country' message. You can find one and try it out.

Comment: Yes, that's´s the reason why I´m asking. I promoted my app and a customer told me he got the same message when tapping my link. Then he searched for the app in the store by typing the name in the AppStore search field and voila he found the app. I got two links on my website - one with de and the other with us. But what happens if somebody in Italy taps on the us link?

Comment: There's a very old thread at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31463/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-generic-country-unrelated-itunes-link, but I'm saying I think if there's a US app and I click the DE link, it'll take me to the US. Gimme your DE link and I'll try it?

Comment: Actually, I found one. Seems to be handled fine; it prompts me to switch to the version available in my country. https://imgur.com/a/nrLYVay'

Comment: DE Link: https://apps.apple.com/de/app/ipracticepro/id1491146332?l=de

Comment: US link: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ipracticepro/id1491146332?l=en

Comment: I opened your DE link and got the US app store on my phone without issues.

Comment: I think they work in Germany and in the US. But I´m worried about user in other countries. They tap on the us link as they don't speak German. So the question is if they could see my app in their store if they tap the us link.

Comment: Can you try again please? I first posted the us link saying it is the German link.

Comment: I did it after your edit; the DE link works fine for me in the US.

Comment: Ok perfect, thank you for you help!